# Performance of group module with thousands of groups

Tags: 8, group

I am planning to make use of the group module and let site users create and maintain their own groups. This will lead to thousands of groups. I am wondering whether site performance would become a serious issue for Drupal maintaining that many new fieldable entities? I'm using Drupal 8.3.2

Comment: Certainly could - the only way you'll know is by trying it on your intended infrastructure and under your expected load. Anything else would be a guess and not provide you with realistic, useful data to make a decision

Comment: BTW 8.3.2 is not a good version to be running right now. Upgrade to 8.5.1, 8.3.9 if you can't do that, or apply the patch from [here](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2018-002) as a matter of urgency